# Lubuntu default keyboard shortcuts for always on top, normal, maximize

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, openbox

I have found that `Windows+Left` put the window in the left, `Windows+Up` put the window in the top...

I was not able to find the default shortcut to `maximize`, `Layer-always on top`, `Layer-normal` and others.

Are there default shortcuts? Must we configure them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu default shortcuts can be found at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Keyboard_shortcuts

Others must be configured by each individual user.

Comment: Windows + Left (= Super + Left) put a window at the left. That shortcut is not in that list!

Answer (score 1):

**F11** toggles a so-called *full-screen* display.

As it leaves tabs & menus on if used on a browser, this is rather a toggle-maximize rather than a toggle-fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `Super_L` entry in your Global Actions Manager (search for "Shortcut Keys" in your Application Menu)

[image: "Super_L" row option deselected in the Global Actions Manager]

Run `sudo featherpad ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` or `sudo nano ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`.

Search for the `<keyboard>` tag using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if you're using Featherpad or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> if you're using the `nano` editor. Insert this after the `keyboard` tag:

```
 <!-- Keybindings for window tiling -->
<keybind key="W-Up">        # FullScreen
    <action name="Maximize"/>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Down">        # MiddleScreen
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>center</x>
        <y>center</y>
        <width>50%</width>
        <height>50%</height>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Left">        # HalfLeftScreen
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>100%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Right">        # HalfRightScreen
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>-0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>100%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-1">        # UpperQuarterLeft
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-2">        # LowerQuarterLeft
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>-0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-3">        # LowerQuarterRight
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>-0</x>
        <y>-0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-4">        # UpperQuarterRight
    <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
    <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>-0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

Save it and run `openbox --reconfigure` in your terminal.

Working on Lubuntu 21.10